# Ruby: mysql2-Gem not working (Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just compiled ruby and installes rubygems, mysql2 and rails, which worked quite well. But I get the following error message, whenever I try to start the rails server:

```
/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
  from /Users/filzo/Documents/rails/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in '
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
  from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `'
```

I tried several possible solutions (e.g. this: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=23125#23125 with libmysqlclient.18.dylib); but nothing worked for me. I hope you can help me.

EDIT:
It seems like this fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Anyway; is it a bug in the MySQL or the ruby-code?

Comment: Your fix worked for me too. I had to change '1.9.1' to '1.8' and my copy of Ruby was installed in the root Library, not the local one but it worked. Woot!

Comment: What mysql version do you use?

Answer (score 31):

One of the simple and best way is to create a soft link by command -

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/07/getting-error-library-not-loaded.html

Comment: Captain Fantastic. After trying this I'm no longer able to log in to mysql. Keep getting access denied error...

Answer (score 15):

This appears to be a known (and unfixed!) [bug in the MySQL binary distribution](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61243).

Whilst running `install_name_tool` on your mysql2.bundle files will work, if you remove and rebuild them you're back to square one.  Also, you'll have to apply this fix to anything else that links against it.  A better solution is to fix the problem in the library itself:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -id \
  /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib \
  /usr/local/mysql-5.5.12-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Removing and rebuilding the mysql2 gem:

```
$ gem uninstall mysql2
$ gem install mysql2
```

...will pick up the change to the library, and everything should work correctly, without having to tinker with any environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, this works best for me! Hope the mysql binary distributions will get fixed.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using RVM (an excellent choice) on Mac OS X - here is the magic command that finally worked for me.

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Users/*USERNAME*/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Replace *USERNAME* in the syntax appropriately as per your current setup.
And if your version of mysql gem is different change that as well.

Comment: It prints `install_name_tool: can't open file: /Users/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (No such file or directory)`

Comment: `install_name_tool` seems to be part of XCode / command line developer tools. A more portable of version of this command is:


`sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib \`bundle show mysql2\`/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle`

Comment: Using the `install_name_tool -id` command below is a better solution for the reasons they outlined.

Answer (score 4):

A better alternative to install_name tool is to add a path the the mysql lib to your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. In /etc/profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Or, as I have the Oracle Instant Client installed as well, do:

```
export ORACLE_HOME="/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_10_2"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to make this symbolic link, so rake can find the correct MySQL client lib.

`ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I'm using OS X 10.7.1 Lion. In my case, I opened a terminal window, went to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7 and as soon as I did RVM barked saying it encountered a new or modified .rvmrc file. The contents of that file was:

```
rvm use 1.9.2@mysql2 --create
```

It asked if I wanted to trust this .rvmc file. I said yes, and it returned the following:

```
Using /Users/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290 with gemset mysql2
```

Once it did, I ran the following command:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

Once I did, I was set to go. Hope this helps!