# Symbol not found: _rb_cFixnum on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

- ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin15]

An error occur when I try to use 'bundle exec rails console'.

```
/hogehoge/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': dlopen(/hogehoge/vendor/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_cFixnum (LoadError)
Referenced from: /hogehoge/vendor/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.6/lib/mysql2/≈
Expected in: flat namespace
```

Message shows dlopen failed to load mysql2.bundle.
I followed instruction in this link [Ruby: mysql2-Gem not working (Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Ruby 1.9.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446747/ruby-mysql2-gem-not-working-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-ruby-1-9-2)

But I can't solve the problem even if libmysqlclient exists in my local.

- /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.32/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
- /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

What's the cause of this error?

Comment: I got a similar error "Symbol not found: _rb_cFixnum", running Chef knife command. I suspect it's more environment related than ruby version related, and switching interpreter versions just has a side effect of changing the environment. In my case, I would get the error under ruby 2.4.3, but not under ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score -1):

That error is shown under ruby 2.4.1.
It worked if I changed my ruby version to 2.3.1